# Ant executes other depending targets even when Fail Task has been executed

Tags: ant

I have an Ant target like this

```
<target name="test-fail"
        depends="run-fail, after-fail"
/>
```

In `run-fail` the task `<fail/>` is executed.

`after-fail` however still runs (is that expected behavior?). At the end, the script does fail, but is there way not to run `after-fail`?

Comment: This should not be the expected behavior. Does `run-fail` somehow depend on `after-fail`?

Comment: No, run-fail doesn't depend on anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not expected behavior in Ant: a `fail` task invokation would exit the current build, and subsequent targets would not be executed.

However, there is one case where your scenario could happen: when running `ant` with the `-keep-going` or `-k` flag (see [this page](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)).

e.g. `ant -k -f buildfile.xml`.

In this case, Ant will still execute targets that do not depend on the failed target. Make sure your buildfile is not launched in this way if you want to avoid this scenario.

If this flag is not enabled, then the only explanation I can see is that some other target is explicitly calling `after-fail` before reaching `test-fail`.

In all cases, running the buildfile with verbose output (using the `-v` flag) can help you understand how Ant is executing the whole sequence.